Как реализовать код при удалении объекта, обходя @Override метода finalize() java?
Мне нужно реализовать некоторый код при удалении объекта из памяти, при этом я не могу использовать перезапись метода finalize(), т.к. он deprecated и, возможно, скоро вообще будет удалён. Какой есть способ для решении моей проблемы?

Возможный дубликат вопроса: Как уничтожить объект правильно в Java?

Как правильно подмечено не нужно использовать finalize() замените на использование интерфейса AutoCloseable в сочетании с блоком try-with-resources
Вот как можно это сделать:
public class MyClass implements AutoCloseable {    
    
    @Override
    public void close() {
        
        System.out.println("Object is being removed from memory.");
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (MyClass obj = new MyClass()) {
            // some action
        } close()
    }
}

В этом примере, при выходе из блока try, метод close() объекта MyClass будет автоматически вызван благодаря интерфейсу AutoCloseable. Вы можете вставить в этот метод код, который нужно выполнить при удалении объекта из памяти.
